# std::format compile time checks if possible, run time otherwise

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt, stdformat

I would like to have a wrapper around `std::format` (or `fmt::format`) that utilizes compile time checks of the format string if possible (i.e. if the format string is known at compile time) and revert to run time checks if not (i.e. if the format string is only known at runtime). Unfortunately I have no idea how to figure out if a compile time check is possible.
What I would need is something like overloading a method on its `consteval` property (what is not possible in C++20 as far as I know) or another way to disambiguate the calls to `Format` in the following example code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

template<typename... Args>
[[nodiscard]] auto Format(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename... Args>
[[nodiscard]] auto Format(std::string_view fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::vformat(fmt, std::make_format_args(args...));
}

std::string foo()
{
    return "Foo{}";
}

constexpr inline std::string_view str = "Foo{}";

int main()
{
    std::cout << Format("Foo{}", "bar") << std::endl; // should be compile time checked
    std::cout << Format(str, "bar") << std::endl; // should be compile time checked
    std::cout << Format(foo(), "bar") << std::endl; // should be run time checked
}
```

Comment: Why? fmt and std::format already has such capability: https://godbolt.org/z/z3W9fGG8E Please describe what is not check at compile time. provide demo.

Comment: fmt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Er1rx8bsq

Comment: Is there an example where your `Format` would work but none of `std::format` and `std::vformat`? Or, you just don't want to remember to type `vformat` when the format string is not constexpr?

Comment: @MarekR Obviously a compile time check can only be performed if the format string is known at compile time. If it is not known at compile time, `std::vformat` has to be used. In {fmt} ther also exists `fmt::runtime` to use a format string that is only known at run time.

Comment: @Eugene The main reason for `Format` is a gradual transition of a huge code base that already calls this method. So basically I don't want to "remember"  to type `vformat` if `format` does not work.

Comment: Is the code base using `printf` formatting? What's the type of format string in your code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible but you can use `fmt::runtime` for cases when the format string is not known at compile time:

```cpp
constexpr std::string_view str = "Foo{}";
std::cout << fmt::format("Foo{}", "bar");            // compile time checked
std::cout << fmt::format(str, "bar");                // compile time checked
std::cout << fmt::format(fmt::runtime(foo()), "bar"; // run time checked
```